# Gorilla mux router not working for particular route

Tags: go, routes, gorilla

I'm having an issue using Gorilla for routing. For some routes it works fine, but for other it does not.

I have the following code:

```
import (
   "github.com/gorilla/mux"
   "github.com/justinas/alice"
)

    mx.Handle("/register", commonHandlers.ThenFunc(registerUser)).Methods("POST").Name("register") // This works
    mx.Handle("/verify", commonHandlers.ThenFunc(verifyUser)).Methods("GET").Name("verify") // Does not work
```

The verifyUser calls the Verify function handler is just suppose to output something to the console, for example:

```
log.Println("This works!")
```

But for some reason, when I visit [example.com/verify](http://example.com/verify), the function Verify never actually gets called. Oddly enough, my AngularJS code actually outputs something when /verify is visited, but my Go code does not.

I have the following configuration in my nginx file, not sure if it may conflict with Gorilla routing.

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied

   root /home/usr/go/src/project/dist/;




    server_name localhost;
    index index.html index.htm;


    location @proxy {

       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;

    }

    location / {

       try_files $uri.html $uri/ @proxy;
       autoindex on;
    }
}
```

Is there something wrong with my routing?

Comment: By "it doesn't work" - what happens? Does nothing get output to the browser? Do you get a HTTP status code? Is your Angular front end intercepting the request and not passing it to Go?

Comment: can you post your commonHandlers.ThenFunc(verifyUser)  method as well  the HTTP status

Comment: @elithrar I don't get a status code without the AngularJS code because for some reason /verify never gets handled in Go. I have tried it with and without AngularJS and nothing works. I'm expecting an output of "This works!" on the console to show that the route matches, but that never happens.

Comment: my suggestion is try to debug your application with debugger, it would be easier to know what actually happened.

Comment: @mission.liao What type of debugger should I use? I have been using Firebug to check my status code.

Comment: You could try https://github.com/mailgun/godebug to debug your golang application.

Comment: Could you post the rest of your nginx configuration (particularly the server block) and the code that is calling this.  I had a similar issue and it was because I was calling with a www subdomain and not re-writing non-www requests to www requests in nginx

Comment: @nkhumphreys The rest of the configuration has been posted.

Comment: @dtrinh100 do you have a file called verify.html at your root (/home/usr/go/src/project/dist/) or a verify/index.html in the same place?  Or, have your tried running this and calling localhost:9000/verify rather than going through nginx, this will show whether it is a problem in your Go code or a problem in your nginx config.